# Add Microsoft Work account to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, online-accounts, microsoft

I'm trying to add my Microsoft work account to ubuntu 20.04 on Settings -> Online Accounts.
However, when I click on it, it asks for my password, which indicates it only supports personal accounts. Is that the case?

Normally other applications that integrate with Microsoft, after providing the email address, ask if it's a personal or a work/school account. Is there a way to force that behavior here?
In case you don't know, for work accounts the authentication is handled via my workplace's SAML federation, and not via Microsoft directly.

Comment: Stll the same problem on 20.04+